# Laravel / Eloquent / json "where" contains and "doesnt" contain

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have two filters:
`allowed` and `blocked` that are casted json and contain list of users that are allowed to view a record. For example:

```
record_id 1 
allowed ["1","2"] // nullable
blocked ["5","6"] // nullable
```

Now I need to select all records that a particular `user_id` can view.

```
Records::where(function ($query) use ($user_id) {
        $query->where("allowed->$user_id", '!=', null)
            ->orWhere("allowed", null);
    })->where("blocked->$user_id", null)->get();
```

This doesn't work and I'm trying to figure out the correct approach. Does anyone see the problem with the above code.

Comment: Use single-quoted strings, not double-quoted strings because PHP will interpolate variable's values directly into the string. Your `"allowed->$user_id"` becomes `"allowed->1"` which is meaningless.

Comment: Seems to me like that's exactly what he wants to do here

Comment: This is the way I usually access fields within the json field.
Like `config: {'name', 'John'}` => `where('config->name', 'John')`

Comment: I think the problem might be because the `allowed` and `blocked` are actually arrays, not an "object".

Comment: I recasted it from json to array. Now I can access it like
`'allowed->0'`
`'allowed->1'`
`'allowed->2'`
Still not sure how to see if user_id is within the values

Comment: I'm leaning towards using the workaround with %like%..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no way of testing this, but I believe this should work:

```
Records::where(function ($query) use ($user_id) {
    $query->whereRaw('JSON_CONTAINS(allowed, ?)', [$user_id])
        ->orWhere('allowed', null);
})->where('JSON_CONTAINS(blocked, ?) = 0', [$user_id])->get();
```

Basically, you're searching a json list, so you need to use `JSON_CONTAINS`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `whereIn` of `whereNotIn` functions of laravel. You pass the array as the second parameter for the function.

[Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections)

Comment: I'm looking for a reverse here. I want to supply a variable and find out if array of values within json filed contains it.